# node Attributes[] array giving additional attributes in IE

Tags: javascript

I am using "node.attributes" to retrieve  all the attributes of a DOM node using JavaScript in IE.
It gives me additional attributes which are not specified in the source .In Firefox it gives only those which are specified in html source (which is expected).

is there any way to retrieve "only the attributes" of a DOM elements which are specified in its HTML source in IE?

Thanks in advance.

-Sourabh

Comment: @maksymko: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-637646024

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attributes have a [`specified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534637(VS.85).aspx) property which is `true` if the attribute was specified in the HTML source or explicitly set by script.